# How to get current value of UITextField in cocos2d 0.8.2?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Hi all I am using cocos2d 0.8.2 for my new game. I have added a UITextField in my game and on click of a button (this button is actually a sprite i m using ccTouchesEnded! ) i save text field's value in database, but whenever i access the value i am getting nil. if i initialize the textfield value by some string, it always give me only that value. 
i.e.

```
[txtField setText:@"Enter Your Name"];
```

when i access the value of txtField on a click of button it always give me "Enter Your Name". Although the value is changing when i type in textField, but its not returning me the new value.

is this a issue with cocos2d 0.8.2 or i am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You don't save the entered text. You just set @"Enter your Name" as default text, that is displayed in the cell. You should have a look at the UITextFieldDelegate methods. You have to overwrite the method didEndEditing, that is called after your editing or typing in text has ended, and implement there a line that saves the current value. Here you can use something like this:

```
NSString *containerForTextFieldValue = textField.text;
```